# Aggregate and count conditionally but return all lines

Tags: sql, count, grouping, window-functions, aggregation

The table structure looks like this:

```
+----------+------------+---------------+
| id       | manager_id | restaurant_id |
+----------+------------+---------------+
| 1        | 1          | 1001          |
| 2        | 1          | 1002          | 
| 3        | 2          | 1003          |
| 4        | 2          | 1004          |
| 5        | 2          | 1005          |
| 6        | 3          | 1006          |
+----------+------------+---------------+
```

I want to retrieve all the `restaurant_id` aggregated per `manager_id`. Additionally, I also need to filter per manager's `count(restaurant_id)`: returning only restaurants of managers that have more than one restaurant, and less than `3`.

**Edit**: this is an oversimplified version of the real data, the actual use case must cover `more than one` to `5` (included).

So that in the end, the result would be

```
+---------------+------------+
| restaurant_id | manager_id | 
+---------------+------------+
| 1001          | 1          |
| 1002          | 1          |
+---------------+------------+
```

I tried something similar to:

```
SELECT 
  restaurant_id, 
  manager_id,
  COUNT(*) AS restaurant_count
FROM 
  Manager_Restaurant
GROUP BY 
  manager_id
HAVING 
  restaurant_count > 1 and 
  restaurant_count < 3;
```

But this return only one line per manager because of the grouping and I want all the restaurants.

Comment: What's the purpose of writing > 1 and < 3 instead of = 2? Count always produces integer values. Furthermore, your count selection doesn't make sense in this case, you could also just write SELECT...,2. Are you sure your description is correct?

Comment: Thanks Jonas. This is a simplified version of more complex data. In the real use case, I actually need  `1 > restaurant_count > 5`. Just wanted to keep the example simple, but this is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window (aka analytic) functions were designed with just such a case in mind.

You can use a window function to assign to each row the counts for a particular grouping, then select the rows having the required counts.  Here is an example:

```
create table manager_restaurant (id int,manager_id int,restaurant_id int);
insert into manager_restaurant 
  values (1,1,1001),(2,1,1002),(3,2,1003),(4,2,1004),(5,2,1005),(6,3,1006);


select manager_id,restaurant_id from (
  select *,
    count(1) over (partition by manager_id) as n 
  from 
    manager_restaurant
  )x 
 where 
   n>1 and n<3 ;
```

| manager_id | restaurant_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 |
| 1 | 1002 |

Comment: Thanks for the kind explanation. I was unaware of the window functions existence, what made my searches attempts awkward.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a windowed count here. More than 1 and less than 3 is 2:

```
select restaurant_id, manager_id
from (
  select *, Count(*) over(partition by manager_id) cnt
  from t
)t
where cnt = 2;
```

Comment: I used an oversimplified dataset. I need to search in the `2-5` range, I can then adapt your where clause.

Comment: Ok yes you can, the same basic principle applies just apply the range you need.